# How to convert string to lowercase? .toLowerCase() not working properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I want to make an input field that returns imputed text in lower case. I'm using expo

```
const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
//...
<TextInput style={{backgroundColor:'#bbb'}}
   value={login}
   onChangeText={(val)=>setLogin(val.toLowerCase())}
   placeholder="email or username"
></TextInput>
```

I'm getting a strange result when testing it on my device.

my input: 'K' => login = 'k'

my input: 'k' => login = 'kkk'

my input: 'k' => login = 'kkkkkkk'

You may need to try a few times to recreate my result as it doesn't happen every time. When I remove `.toLowerCase()`, it works correctly.

I made [runnable example](https://snack.expo.dev/@perasa3a/tolowercase-error) for you to test. Running it in web mode works fine, but when I run it on my device, the same error is occurring as in my project.

Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/oM9VT_LMF3g) of what's happening to me when I run it on android 10. You can see that it doesn't happen always, but sometimes it registers as if I've pressed "q" three times when I've only pressed it twice

Comment: Can you try it yourself to see if the error occurs to you as well? Here is my proof that I have removed just ```.toLowerCase()``` and it works [link](https://imgur.com/obVCeCA)

Comment: I put it in ```useEffect(() => {console.log(login)});``` but still get the same result

Comment: Something strange is happening, I made runnable example for you to test. Running it in web mode works fine, but when I run it on my device, the same error is occurring as in my project. Could someone else test it on their phone to see if they get the same error? Here is runnable example [link](https://snack.expo.dev/@perasa3a/dd95bb)

Comment: You can see what I'm talking about in the video I've added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you run into a known `react-native` bug, related to text inputs and capitalization on Android platform. Open github issue [#27449](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27449).

As a workaround you can force the text input to use the `visible-password` keyboard type on Android.

[Working example](https://snack.expo.dev/@vicpermir/f41b9b) for you to test:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput style={{backgroundColor:'#bbb'}}
        value={login}
        onChangeText={(val)=>setLogin(val.toLowerCase())}
        keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'default' : 'visible-password'}
        placeholder="email or username"
      ></TextInput>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 80,
  },
});
```

Credit for the workaround goes to [simon-davies-avtura](https://github.com/simon-davies-avtura)